# Difference between table and tables in proc freq in sas

Tags: sas

Could anyone please tell the difference between table and tables in Proc freq with an example?

```
proc freq data= want;
table variable;
run;

proc freq data= want;
tables variable;
run;`
```

Comment: You need to be more specific and give more details. Also, I don't know what code this is (like if it's specific to your sas tag), so I could just be completely out of my depth, but it looks like nonsense to me.

Comment: better code formatting

Comment: @NonCreature0714 Better to leave alone questions that you don't understand the language than to comment on them.  Beyond the (now fixed) formatting this question is fine.  Skip is a quite valid choice in reviews, and probably should be the most commonly chosen one.

Comment: @Joe thanks Joe. It confused me, I’m not afraid to admit, so I’ll just skip next time.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference. The statement is the `TABLES` statement, but SAS will silently accept `TABLE` as a synonym without issuing any warning or note. Some miss spellings will generate just a warning while others will cause an error.

```
1668  proc freq data= sashelp.class;
1669  tablex age name;
      ------
      1
WARNING 1-322: Assuming the symbol TABLE was misspelled as tablex.
1670  run;

NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.


1671
1672  proc freq data= sashelp.class;
1673  tabl age name;
      ----
      1
WARNING 1-322: Assuming the symbol TABLE was misspelled as tabl.
1674  run;

NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.


1675
1676  proc freq data= sashelp.class;
1677  tab age name;
      ---
      180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
1678  run;

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
```